# SQL Select statement based on login details

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database from which I would like users to retrieve information from a certain table called "entry" based on their username.

So I want user1 to login and then a select statement be created to take the username, look it up in the username table, and then used the stored value for the person's name (which is one of the columns in the user table) to run a query to show all records for that person.

Is this possible?

thanks in advance

EDIT:

Sorry the question was so badly formed. 
Basically I have a users table which holds user login details with the fields - studentName, Site, Username , Password

I then have another table called entry which holds records for all users with the following fields - entryID, date, studentName , field1 , field2, field3 etc

What want to do is for the user to login as they do now and a query to be generated based on the Username to get all records for that particular student.

Does this give a better idea of what I am try to get?

Comment: This can either be done as two queries, or you could run a join query to accomplish this in one step. It sounds like you should read up on queries a little first.

Comment: If you're hoping for some SQL help, simple table definitions would be a good starting point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to be looking at SQL joins, assuming I've understood what you're after correctly (you want to pull user details from a table based on a key value in another table)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly way off but asuming a table called User with an Id, Name & UserName and a related table called details with a UserId and other columns with the details the below simple join will work. Also the string 'AUserName' is the value passed in from your app.

```
SELECT User.Name, Details.*
FROM User
INNER JOIN Details
ON User.Id = Details.UserId
WHERE User.Username = 'AUserName'
```

But this is a guess based on your question, add more details and you'll get a better answer

Answer (score 0):

if its Oracle, then you can do:

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM entry
WHERE username = user  -- user is an Oracle keyword that returns 
                       -- the oracle user name of the user running the query.
```